# After clicking on the login nothing happens

Tags: android, retrofit2

Hi in the below code i have login application . In that contains email id and password. Registration was happening fine with email id and password.

Now, am taking the email Id and password then press on login button am just checking status is success or not. If the status is success then moving to another activity.

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                emailId = et_email.getText().toString();
                password = et_password.getText().toString();
               getlogindetails(emailId, password);

            }
        });


    }
```

**Method.java:**

```
private void getlogindetails(String emailId, String password) {

        if (!validate(emailId)) {
            et_email.requestFocus();
            et_email.setError("Please provide a valid email Id");
            return;
        }
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            et_password.requestFocus();
            et_password.setError("Please provide password");
            return;
        }
        if (!CheckWifiAndMobileData.IsConnected(LoginActivity.this)) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
String url = "http://172.24.1.1:9000";

        Retrofit retrofit = null;
        Log.d("123", "retrofit");

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
            Log.d("123", "build();");
        }
        API1 service = retrofit.create(API1.class);

        Call<Login> call = service.authenticate(this.emailId, password);
        Log.i(TAG, "Sending---" + url + service + "\n" + "light_id:" + this.emailId + "\n" + "intensity:" + password );

        //final String EmailId = emailId;
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Login> call, Response<Login> response) {
                String status=response.body().getStatus().toString();
                if (status.contains("success")) {
                    // showResponse(response.body().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent mainIntent;
                  mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DeviceControlActivity.class);
                  mainIntent.putExtra("emailId", LoginActivity.this.emailId);
                 startActivity(mainIntent);
                 finish();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid EmailId and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Login> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to submit post to API.");
            }
        });
    }
```

**API1.java**

```
 interface API1 {

    @POST("app_login/")
        Call<Login> authenticate(@Path("emailId") String emailId, @Path("password") String password);
    }
```

Comment: That's a great scenario to use a debugger

Comment: Post the log details

Comment: where is your if(response.isSuccessful()) {}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why you are using `@Path` inside interface method. It must be `@Body`
>   or `@Field`

**Don't use `@Path`**

```
 @POST("app_login/")
        Call<Login> authenticate(@Path("emailId") String emailId, @Path("password") String password);
```

Try to use like this , create Pojo for your request like this

```
public class Request{
  private String emailId;
  private String password;
}
```

and use like this

```
 @POST("app_login")
     Call<Login> authenticate(@Body Request data);
```

**Or**

use like this

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("app_login")
    Call<Login> authenticate(@Field("emailId") String emailId, @Field("password") String password);
```

Note:- `@Path` is used when your API `url` is changing accordingly different user. Example you are fetching data according to user id.

Comment: Not equal it's equals

Comment: yes `contains` use for arraylist and for comparison of string `equals` used.

Comment: It depends on the endpoint, if it waits for data in query param, then you have to use path, and also, in this case you should consult with the backend team. Also, you do not have to check the status like this, what is the response? As @Ashish said, response.isSuccessful()

Comment: String status=response.body().getStatus().toString(); saving the response in status string.

Comment: @barotia i given example where `@path` is use

Comment: @barotia postman response is this.because of that am stroing the response body in string and then checking the status.{"status":"success"}

Comment: @jyocha he has point about checking  `response.isSuccessful()` is provide you that your APi is hit on server successfully with code 200.    `response.isSuccessful()` is a retrofit variable .

Comment: @SushilKumar small doubt url for checking localhost is not working .can you help me

Comment: Sure tell me now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186447/discussion-between-jyo-cha-and-sushil-kumar).